# Angular - Retrieve values of the matching element of an object array contained within an object array

Tags: angular

I need to retrieve values of the matching element of an object array contained within an object array.

The main object here is FundClasses and it contains an object array called FundDetailsViewModel. The FundDetailsViewModel contains an array of objects. The record I am searching for is in the object FundClassDetailsViewModel. The FundClassDetailsViewModel contains Id element and I am trying to filter based on that Id which is unique across all objects. For e.g if I am am filtering based id 305583 , it should retrieve that record from the object array.

Screenshot of the Fundclasses object

[image]

This is what I was trying

```
this.FundClass = this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.forEach(x => {
              x.Id = id;
          });
```

I also tried this but it is giving me an error this.FundClasses.find is not a function

```
    this.FundClass = this.FundClasses.find(x => 
            x.FundDetailsViewModel.FundClassDetailsViewModel.Id === id
        );
```

Json structure

```
{"FundDetailsViewModel":[{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":1121,"FundId":652,"ShareClass":"Class B","LocalCurrency":"USD","Name":"Class B USD"}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":305583,"Description":null,"InvestedAmount":900000,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":103,"ClosureStatusName":"In Liquidation","IsSidePocket":true,"IsThematic":true,"VehicleTypeId":1,"VehicleTypeName":"FX Trade","FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250028,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":23732600,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":1121,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250029,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":119307314,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13717,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250030,"Description":"Class B1","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13716,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B1","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250031,"Description":"Class C","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13715,"LegalFundClassName":"Class C","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250032,"Description":"Class D","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13714,"LegalFundClassName":"Class D","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":305581,"Description":"T","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B1","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class C","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class D","ClassType":3}]},{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":0,"FundId":0,"ShareClass":"Assign Cogency Fund First","LocalCurrency":null,"Name":"Assign Cogency Fund First "}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":100541,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11167,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"},{"Id":250033,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11166,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":1},{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":1}]}],"VehicleTypes":[{"Id":108,"Spf":false,"Name":"Secondaries","SortOrder":null,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":100,"Spf":false,"Name":"Co-Investment (non-SPF)","SortOrder":1,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":1,"Spf":false,"Name":"FX Trade","SortOrder":2,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":3,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed ETF","SortOrder":3,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":4,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed Security","SortOrder":4,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":2,"Spf":false,"Name":"Mutual Fund","SortOrder":5,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":5,"Spf":false,"Name":"Offshore Fund","SortOrder":6,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":6,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":7,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":9,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US Non - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":8,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":8,"Spf":false,"Name":"EnTrustPermal Product","SortOrder":9,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":7,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Standard","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":105,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – 40 Act","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":106,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – UCITS","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":102,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Blocker","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":103,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Co-Investment","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":104,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Special Sit","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":10,"Spf":false,"Name":"Private Equity","SortOrder":11,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":101,"Spf":false,"Name":"Side-Pocket","SortOrder":12,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":11,"Spf":false,"Name":"Special Situation (non-SPF)","SortOrder":13,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":12,"Spf":false,"Name":"Third Party Fund of Funds","SortOrder":14,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":13,"Spf":false,"Name":"UCITS","SortOrder":15,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":14,"Spf":false,"Name":"Other","SortOrder":50,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false}],"ClosureStatuses":[{"Id":110,"Name":"Hard Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":111,"Name":"Open","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":112,"Name":"Soft Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":1,"Name":"Open - to all","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Open - to Permal only","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Closed - hard","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":104,"Name":"Closed - with wait list","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":4},{"Id":100,"Name":"Closed - but will reopen","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":21,"Name":"Closed - but replacing redemptions","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":6},{"Id":101,"Name":"Redemptions Gated","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":7},{"Id":102,"Name":"Redemptions Suspended","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":8},{"Id":103,"Name":"In Liquidation","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":9}]}
```

FundClasses declaration

```
public get FundClasses(): any {
    return this._fundClasses;
}
@Input()
public set FundClasses(value: any) {
    this._fundClasses = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the models into a single array and then find on that.

```js
var FundClasses = {"FundDetailsViewModel":[{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":1121,"FundId":652,"ShareClass":"Class B","LocalCurrency":"USD","Name":"Class B USD"}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":305583,"Description":null,"InvestedAmount":900000,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":103,"ClosureStatusName":"In Liquidation","IsSidePocket":true,"IsThematic":true,"VehicleTypeId":1,"VehicleTypeName":"FX Trade","FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250028,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":23732600,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":1121,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250029,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":119307314,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13717,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250030,"Description":"Class B1","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13716,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B1","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250031,"Description":"Class C","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13715,"LegalFundClassName":"Class C","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250032,"Description":"Class D","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13714,"LegalFundClassName":"Class D","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":305581,"Description":"T","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B1","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class C","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class D","ClassType":3}]},{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":0,"FundId":0,"ShareClass":"Assign Cogency Fund First","LocalCurrency":null,"Name":"Assign Cogency Fund First "}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":100541,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11167,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"},{"Id":250033,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11166,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":1},{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":1}]}],"VehicleTypes":[{"Id":108,"Spf":false,"Name":"Secondaries","SortOrder":null,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":100,"Spf":false,"Name":"Co-Investment (non-SPF)","SortOrder":1,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":1,"Spf":false,"Name":"FX Trade","SortOrder":2,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":3,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed ETF","SortOrder":3,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":4,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed Security","SortOrder":4,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":2,"Spf":false,"Name":"Mutual Fund","SortOrder":5,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":5,"Spf":false,"Name":"Offshore Fund","SortOrder":6,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":6,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":7,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":9,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US Non - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":8,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":8,"Spf":false,"Name":"EnTrustPermal Product","SortOrder":9,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":7,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Standard","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":105,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – 40 Act","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":106,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – UCITS","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":102,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Blocker","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":103,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Co-Investment","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":104,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Special Sit","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":10,"Spf":false,"Name":"Private Equity","SortOrder":11,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":101,"Spf":false,"Name":"Side-Pocket","SortOrder":12,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":11,"Spf":false,"Name":"Special Situation (non-SPF)","SortOrder":13,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":12,"Spf":false,"Name":"Third Party Fund of Funds","SortOrder":14,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":13,"Spf":false,"Name":"UCITS","SortOrder":15,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":14,"Spf":false,"Name":"Other","SortOrder":50,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false}],"ClosureStatuses":[{"Id":110,"Name":"Hard Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":111,"Name":"Open","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":112,"Name":"Soft Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":1,"Name":"Open - to all","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Open - to Permal only","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Closed - hard","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":104,"Name":"Closed - with wait list","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":4},{"Id":100,"Name":"Closed - but will reopen","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":21,"Name":"Closed - but replacing redemptions","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":6},{"Id":101,"Name":"Redemptions Gated","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":7},{"Id":102,"Name":"Redemptions Suspended","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":8},{"Id":103,"Name":"In Liquidation","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":9}]}
var models = FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.FundClassDetailsViewModel), []);

//this.FundClass = models.find(obj => obj.Id === 305583);
console.log(models.find(obj => obj.Id === 305583));
```

Comment: I am not getting an error but it is not filtering. I can see all the other ids as well

Comment: Are you wanting it to return a single FundClassDetailsViewModel object or the entire FundClassDetailsViewModel that contains that object

Comment: The FundDetailsViewModel will contain multiple FundClassDetailsViewModel object but with those object there will only one record that will always match the key

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what do you want this.FundClass to equal? The single object or the parent of that object?

Comment: just the single object